# Can't view Apache Airflow GUI on using GCP Compute Engine

Tags: networking, google-compute-engine, airflow

As mentioned in the title, I would like to setup a fully working apache-airflow instance using GCP Compute Engine. I am currently unable to view the gui as I cannot connect to the http://:8080 or https://:8080

Upon creation of the GCP Compute VM I have allowed both HTTP & HTTPS. I have also visited the Cloud Console Network section and created a firewall rule.

I am using a n1-standard-1 vm instance with Ubuntu 18.04 on the 'default' network. For the firewall rule I have created it for the default network to allow tcp:8080 to be opened. Does the name and target have any impact?

I have been able to successfully get the 'airflow webserver' up and running. I have gone over many tutorials of setting up Airflow and have gone through complex and simple tutorials. But all fail to mention at the end how to get the GUI working. I have been following this tutorial relatively closely:

https://medium.com/grensesnittet/install-apache-airflow-on-a-google-cloud-platform-virtual-machine-f9a5b01b6c33

I then decided to dumb it down with the quick start of apache airflow to get it working with the sqllite db.

Upon attempting to reach the http or https url (https://:8080) I get a 'this site cannot be reached' error.

Any help would be very much appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

The solution ended up being the target in the firewall rule. I updated the firewall rule to target all instances in the network, then the GUI popped up. Problem solved. Keep in mind this is not a good long-term solution, but it does allow one to experiment.